# Form Serialization sending data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a question with regards to form serialization in PHP/jQuery. Here is my code below:

```
    <form name="myForm" method="post" action="page.php">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Field 1</td><td>Field 2</td><td>Field 3</td>
        </tr>
         <?php
          $i = 0;
         while ($tempInfo=mysql_fetch_array(query)) {
            $field1       =  $tempInfo['field1'];
            $field2       =  $tempInfo['field2'];
            $field3       =  $tempInfo['field3'];  

          ?>
           <tr>
              <td><input type="hidden value="<?php echo $field1?>"> name=testValue</td><td><?php echo $field2 ?></td><td><?php echo $field3?></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="myCheckboxes[]" id="myCheckboxes" value="getReport_<?php echo $i;?>" /></td></tr>
          <?php
              }
           ?>
        </table>
        <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm()" /></form><div id="myResponse"></div>
```

Then here is the jQuery code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function submitForm() {
          var form = document.myform;
          var dataString = $(form).serialize();
          $.ajax({
               type:'POST',
               url:'report-gen.php',
               data: dataString,
               success: function(data){
                 $('#myResponse').html(data);
               }
            });
           return false;
           }
           </script>
```

Here is the problem, the data is being sent but only the data on the last row, not based on the checkbox. How can I make sure the only data that is being sent is the one that has the checkbox selected?

Comment: Can you share the actual markup that is created?

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple fields with the same name, PHP will discard all but the last one if that name does not end in `[]` (which `testValue` does not). Rename your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the hidden field you could put all the data in the checkbox and parse it on the return.  For example change the value to:

```
value="getReport_<?php echo $i;?>|$field1"
```

To get the different values do

```
list($report, $field1) = explode("|", $checkbox_value);
```